# How do I get only one specific aspect of the JSON answer

Tags: python, json

so I have the following block of JSON:

```
b'{"data":[{"categories":[{"id":"IAB3","label":"Business","parent":"IAB3","score":"0.223819028028717559","confident":true}],"url":"megatel.de"}]}'
```

I need only a String with the content of the first label field.

Comment: What would be the expected output for your example?

Comment: Parse JSON into a data structure with the stock `json` module, then retrieve the necessary member. Any tutorial should cover that.

Comment: Generally, you would use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to convert the string/bytearray into a native Python data structure. From there, I'm sure you'll be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Following snippet returns the output as `Business`

```
import json
data = json.loads('{"data":[{"categories":[{"id":"IAB3","label":"Business","parent":"IAB3","score":"0.223819028028717559","confident":true}],"url":"megatel.de"}]}')
print(data['data'][0]['categories'][0]['label'])
```

If you have more of such data, you could iterate over the `data` variable and get the desired results by substituting the `0` indices with the iterateor at both the places.

For example, if the json is somewhat as follows

```
{"data":
        [
            {"categories":
                [
                    {"id":"IAB3",
                    "label":"Business",
                    "parent":"IAB3",
                    "score":"0.223819028028717559",
                    "confident":true}
                ],
            "url":"megatel.de"
            },
            {"categories":
                [
                    {"id":"IAB3",
                    "label":"Business",
                    "parent":"IAB3",
                    "score":"0.223819028028717559",
                    "confident":true}
                ],
                "url":"megatel.de"
            }
        ]
}
```

You could use the following  script to get similar output.

```
for entry in data['data']:
    for categories in entry['categories']:
        print categories['label']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = b'{"data":[{"categories":[{"id":"IAB3","label":"Business","parent":"IAB3","score":"0.223819028028717559","confident":true}],"url":"megatel.de"}]}' 
(x.split('"label":')[1]).split(",")[0][1:-1]
>>'Business'
```

Comment: Won't work when label is the last key (you'll have `}` instead of `,`).

Answer (score 0):

If you can also try a regex approach:

```
import re


txt = b'{"data":[{"categories":[{"id":"IAB3","label":"Business","parent":"IAB3","score":"0.223819028028717559","confident":true}],"url":"megatel.de"}]}'

pattern = r'"label":"(.*?)"'
labels = re.search(pattern, str(txt, 'utf-8')).groups()

print(labels[0])  # Business
```